# Picture becomes blurry when connecting Laptop to HD TV via  HDMI

Tags: windows-7, laptop, hdmi, external-display

I have connected my new Acer S3 to my P2270HD Samsung 1080P TV. I selected 1920x1080 and adjusted the picture as good as possible, but the picture is very blurry.

Previously I used the VGA input from a Dell laptop and it was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more likely that this is being caused by a setting on your TV. For example, my TV has blur/sharpen/movie/bright modes...

I can't be specific to your TV so my advise is general..

When I first plugged my TV into my computer, the aspect ratio was incorrect for my computer resolution and my graphics card was compensating for this by over scanning the picture, making it bigger to fit the screen.

This made my text really sharp, so I couldn't read it properly without putting the blur display mode on. Until I susses out the TV menu enough to set it up correctly.

You can always reset settings to default after you've fiddled, read the manual if you get lost.

Comment: Don't forget the overscan mode some TVs use - may be also a source of "blurry".

Answer (score 0):

In my case by default windows select 59Hz refresh rate while my TV supports 60Hz refresh rate. When I changed it to 60Hz issue got fixed.